# How many grave diggers are needed?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

A mob boss in the middle of a mob war recently had 4 of his henchmen dig 3 graves. Working as fast as they could the task was completed in 20 minutes.

The following week, the mob boss heard rumors about an attack soon to be ordered by a rival mob boss. Hoping for peace but preparing for possible violence, the mob boss asks:

> How many henchmen working at the same pace would I need to dig 27 graves in 60 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the mob boss would need:

> 12 grave diggers

Because:

> If 4 can dig 3 graves in 20 minutes, they can dig 9 in 60 minutes. Therefore 9*3 = 27 so 4*3 = 12 diggers are needed

Answer (score 3):

> 12
>  
>  For 3 graves-> 4*20= 80, therefore for 9 graves 80*9=720. Then we have only 60 min. So 720/60 = 12.

Answer (score 1):

> Twelve. 4 digging 3 graves every 20 minutes would dig 9 in one hour. 
>  27 grave divided by 9 is 3 teams of 4, and 3x4 = 12.